# How to sort LDAP Result with LDAP Query?

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query, novell

I'm creating a LDAP directory search using PHP and we're using Novell as our LDAP server. I'm able to successfully search and return results; this is the current filter I'm running, `(&(FERPA=N)(|(uid=*searchphrase*)(sn=*searchphrase*)(fullName=*searchphrase*)(telephoneNumber=*searchphrase*)))`.

I want to be able to sort by last name, or the LDAP variable `sn`. I could sort it via PHP, but I want that to be the last resort. Is there a way to sort the results based on a column. For example, in SQL you can sort based on a column like this, `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL='criteria' ORDER BY COL;` Is there something similar that can be done with LDAP Queries?

Comment: Just wondering if you know about this ldap_sort function(http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-sort.php).

Comment: I've looked into it, but I wasn't able to find documentation for that specific function. Plus, I'm trying to sort the results via LDAP Queries, if I can't figure out a way to do it via LDAP Queries, then I will resort to sorting via PHP.

Answer (score 3):

LDAP client applications that require results of search requests to be ordered in a repeatable
way should use the [server-side sort extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2891). In most
cases, use of the server-side sort extension requires the application coder to inform the
directory administrators so that proper indexing can be setup.

Comment: SOrry I might be missing something, but how does this help my question about sorting LDAP Results via LDAP Queries?

Comment: It doesn't. It's not the simple paged results but the [server-side sort extension](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2891). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to sort results with a LDAP filter. All a filter does is limit what entries are returned.

With php, you would run your search, then sort the result with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-sort.php

Alternatively, you could read all the entries into an array and then run one of php's other sorting functions on them. https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php